# Using ViewModels and Partial View with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am having a problem with creating an appropriate ViewModel to allow me to allow user to choose multiple tickets at once in a View.

I have a Ticket model

```
 public class Ticket
{
   public int TicketID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [ForeignKey("Event")]
   //foreign key
    public int EventID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Description { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public float Price { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

}
```

An Order Model

```
 public class Order
{

    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventID { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float OrderTotal { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser user { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have an OrderDetails model

```
public class OrderDetails
{

    [Required]
    public int OrderDetailsID { get; set; }


    [Required]
    //Foreign key
    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //Foreign key
    [ForeignKey("Ticket")]
    public int TicketID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }

}
```

I also created an additional TicketsOrdered model as I don't know where else I can save the quantity of each ticket type a user has selected

```
public class TicketsOrdered
{

    public int OrderID;

    public int TicketID;

    public int Quantity;
}
```

I want to create a View which will display the Ticket Description and Price for each Ticket relating to a specific Event then there will also be a dropdown/textbox to allow users to input the quantity of each ticket they require. Then I want to save the TicketID, OrderID and quantity to my TicketsOrdered db table. The problem I am having is that all the data is relating to so many models and I don't know how to bring it all together. I'm at a total loss on how to achieve this, an example of how I want it to look is when you click book tickets on EventBrite.
Any help on a ViewModel which will work or how to use my current models in a View would be really helpful thank you.

**EDIT**
Event Model

```
 public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Total Tickets Available")]
    public int TicketsAvailable { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public virtual IEnumerable<Order> Order { get; set; }
    //navigation property
    public virtual IEnumerable<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You state _for each Ticket relating to a specific Event_, but your models suggest you only have one Ticket per event, not a collection of Tickets. What is your `Event` model? Does it contain a property `IEnumerable<Order>`?

Comment: Yes I have an Event model contain IEnumerable <Order> @StephenMuecke. Which model do I need to change to show each event can have multiple tickets? Thanks

Comment: Its still a little unclear what your relationships are. Does each `Event` have also have a collection of different `Ticket` types? And is the idea that you want to create an `Order` for an `Event` which displays all the available ticket types for that `Event` and allow the user to enter a quantity for each (say they want 2 standard tickets and 2 deluxe tickets)?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to be able to do @StephenMuecke

Comment: OK - no time now, but I will add an answer in an hour or so showing how the view model and view should be. Note also its unclear why you have separate models for `Order` and `OrderDetails` since there seems to be a 1:1 relationship between them

Comment: Thank you very much @StephenMuecke I thought I would need the order details model as I want to store the name email and phone of each ticket holder. Also I created this before the tickets ordered model as I thought that I wouldn't need to store the quantity anywhere if I had an orderDetails table. However i appwar to have been wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating view models that represent what you want to display/edit in the view

```
public class TicketVM
{
  public int TicketID { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
public class OrderVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int EventID { get; set; }
  public string EventName { get; set; }
  // additional properties of Event you want to display
  public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  // additional properties of Order and OrderDetails you want to edit
  public List<TicketVM> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Side note: Its a bit unclear why you have separate models for `Order` and `OrderDetails`, or why `OrderDetails` has `public int TicketID { get; set; }` which suggests an `Order` can only have one ticket so I suggest you may need some changes to your database structure. If the intention is that a user can order multiple tickets for different people, then the name, email and phone of each ticket holder should probably be stored in the `TicketsOrdered` table (and those properties added to the `TicketVM` class)

The view would then be (assuming its for a Create method)

```
@model TicketVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EventID)
  <h2>@Model.EventName</h2>
  // other display properties of event
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderDate)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
  // other edit control for properties of Order and OrderDetails (see note above)
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tickets)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and the `EditorTemplate` for `TicketVM` (in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TicketVM.cshtml`)

```
@model TicketVM
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TicketID)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Price)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity)
```

Then the controller methods would be (note you have not shown you `Event` model so adjust the following to suit)

```
public ActionResult Create(int ID) // assumes ID is the ID of the Event
{
  // Get the event and its tickets
  Event e = db.Events.Where(e = e.EventID = ID).Include(e => e.Tickets);
  // Initialize a new order
  OrderVM model = new OrderVM
  {
    EventID = e.EventID,
    EventName = e.EventName,
    // other properties of event as required
    Tickets = e.Tickets.Select(t => new TicketVM
    {
      TicketID = t.TicketID,
      Description = t.Description,
      Price = t.Price
    })
  };
  return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OrderVM model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // repopulate any properties as required
    return View(model);
  }
  // Initialize an Order data model, save it and gets its ID
  Order order = new Order
  {
    OrderDate = model.OrderDate,
    // other properties of Order
  };
  db.Orders.Add(order);
  db.SaveChanges();
  // ditto for OrderDetails (but see notes above)

  // Initialize an TicketsOrdered data model for each valid ticket
  foreach(TicketVM ticket in model.Tickets.Where(t => t.Quantity > 0))
  {
    TicketsOrdered ticketOrder = new TicketsOrdered
    {
      OrderID = order.ID,
      TicketID = ticketOrder.TicketID,
      Quantity = ticketOrder.Quantity
    }
    db.TicketsOrdered.Add(ticketOrder);
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke. I made an error when I said I had IEnnumerable<Ticket> within my Event model. Then now when I added this to the model I don't know how to add a Ticket to it. I have updated my post to include the Event model. I tried changing IEnnumerable to IList instead so I can use an Add method but this threw an exception concerning this line Tickets = e.Tickets.Select(t => new TicketVm {

Comment: Cant see any update with the `Event` model. But if it does not include a collection property for tickets, then you can populate the `OrderVM` using something like `Tickets = db.Tickets.Where(t => t.EventID = ID).Select(t => new TicketVM { TicketID = t.TicketID, Description = t.Description, Price = t.Price })`. But as I mentioned earlier, I suspect there may be a few problems with the design of you database

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for all your help, I really appreciate you taking your time to help me out @StephenMuecke!